# Was stable now keeps crashing

Tags: crash

My Pi keeps locking up - cannot interact with it via keyboard (even Ctrl-Alt-PrintScr commands) or anything else. Screen (console) frozen.

Pulling power out and rebooting brings it up looking fine again, and there's nothing in syslog/`journalctl -k` around the time of the crashes - it just plain freezes up.

It's been in use for 24 months or so and has been reliable up to now.

I did once catch a screenful of kernel death messages (usually there's nothing on screen to indicate a problem) - I can upload that if helpful.

Details:

- Pi 3b running raspbian 9.
- Has Gigabit USB ethernet adaptor (yes yes I know it's usb2 but it's still faster than 100MBs ethernet)
- Has external RAIDed drives via USB
- Has TV stick
- Runs samba, nginx, mysql, php 7.0 - sometimes heavy use, but it's not been under heavy use when it's died recently.
- official PSU

Anyone any ideas?

Comment: "Anyone any ideas?" **Yes** - restore from your backup.

Comment: Ah yes... actually I think it's an SD card issue. Humph.

Comment: @artfulrobot, Ah yes, I also use Win10 Samba (and Rpi4 PureFTP).  I have 26 micro SD cards, rotating weekly.  Any old SD card showing symptoms of aging, dementia, etc, will immediately RIP and replaced by a new born SD baby.

Comment: How often does the RasPi stuck? Once a day? Every minute? Unplug all devices and replug them step by step. With what device plugged in does it lock up?

Comment: What is sdcard configs?

Comment: @SohanArafat thanks but I've confirmed it's the SD card by trying a write benchmark on another linux machine - there are parts of it that can't be written/read. I'm going to get a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this was a damaged filesystem on the SD card.

Sorry for desparate posting!

I forced an fsck by adding `fsck.mode=force` to `/boot/cmdline.txt` and it's been OK since. I have my suspicions that a small child pulled the power wire out at some point...

I'm stil worried there could be corruption on the sdcard, so I plan to do a full offline test of it and anyway reinstall with Buster as I'm still on Stretch.

Thanks for comment replies.